# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - Java - no loop print

Tags: java, csv, exception

I have a method that's reading a local CSV file and storing it in an array. I keep getting a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I try to print one of the index of the array.

The method:

```
   public void getCsv() throws FileNotFoundException{

    String fileName = "ADCSV.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName);

    Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);

    while(inputStream.hasNext()){

        String data = inputStream.next();

         //array of strings
        String[] values = data.split(",");
        System.out.println(values[4]);


    }

    inputStream.close();

}
```

All of the information in the csv is stored as general text.  When I try to print this is the output:

```
    "adminCount"
    "1"
    "0"
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at csvTest.test.getCsv(test.java:36)
    at csvTest.test.main(test.java:19)
```

It starts to read the values from that particular column fine. It then errors out.

I feel like I've been looking at the problem for awhile now and looking right past the issue.

Thanks

Comment: If you really don't have any line in the CSV with less than 5 items, my guess would be the last line is empty and is still being read. Include your CSV if you prefer something better than guesses.

Comment: Evidently not all the rows have 5 elements. Have you checked what `values` actually holds?

Comment: How does your CSV file looks like? If values contain spaces like `aa,bb bb,cc,d,e,f` then `next()` will return only `aa,bb` because of space between `bb bb`. To solve it you would need `nextLine()` instead of `next()`. Also lets not forget that `split` removes trailing empty strings. So `"a,b,,,".split(",")` will return array `[a, b]` not `[a,b, , , ]`. To solve it you could use `split(",", -1)`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yeah I just ran it through the debugger and all rows have more than at least 5 elements and values is being populated by entire CSV

I can't post screenshots or i'd post one of the debugger.

Comment: @Blurr.P That can't be the case. You have `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4`. I can only see one place where you do any indexing, and the hard coded 4 you're using matches the exception. Look at the data again.

Comment: `split` is probably returning something other than what you expect.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Looks like the issue is to do with white space. Althrough there are a few thousand elements in the column the moment it hits any white space(blank cell in the csv) it exceptions out.

Comment: @Blurr.P You might want to use a regex that takes into account whitespace instead of just splitting on commas.

Comment: can you print sample of that csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method to:

```
public void getCsv() throws FileNotFoundException {

    String fileName = "ADCSV.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName);

    Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);

    while (inputStream.hasNext()) {

        String data = inputStream.next();

        // array of strings
        String[] values = data.split(",");
        if (values.length < 5) {
            System.err.println("not enough values: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                System.err.println("value " + i + ": " + values[i]);
            }
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(values[4]);

    }

    inputStream.close();

}
```

That should show the problem. I mean it will print out the values of the line where the error will occur. Since we don't know what exactly produced the error this will be a start. Maybe somewhere is a comma where it shouldn't be or it is missing.
If the content of the local CSV file can contain errors then it would be appropriate to check the length of the splitted line and set up an error handling.

Comment: Really, you should explain your answer instead of assuming that it's self-evident. This also just seems to catch bad parses instead of actually fixing the parsing.